# Navigating through Vue.Js survey

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm using Vue.Js for a survey, which is basically the main part and the purpose of the app. I have problem with the navigation. My prev button doesn't work and next keeps going in circles instead of only going forward to the next question. What I'm trying to accomplish is just to have only one question visible at a time and navigate through them in correct order using next and prev buttons and store the values of each input which I'll later use to calculate the output that will be on the result page, after the survey has been concluded. I've uploaded on fiddle a short sample of my code with only two questions just to showcase the problem. https://jsfiddle.net/cgrwe0u8/

```
    new Vue({
  el: '#quizz',
  data: {
    question1: 'How old are you?',
    question2: 'How many times do you workout per week?',
    show: true,
    answer13: null,
    answer10: null

  }

})

document.querySelector('#answer13').getAttribute('value');
document.querySelector('#answer10').getAttribute('value');
```

HTML

```
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="quizz" class="question">
    <h2 v-if=show>{{ question1 }}</h2>
    <input v-if=show type="number" v-model="answer13">
    <h2 v-if="!show">{{ question2 }}</h2>
    <input v-if="!show" type="number" v-model="answer10">
    <br>
<div class='button' id='next'><a href='#' @click="show = !show">Next</a></div>
<div class='button' id='prev'><a href='#' @click="show = show">Prev</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at making a Vue component that is for a survey question that way you can easily create multiple different questions.

```
Vue.component('survey-question', {
  template: `<div><h2>{{question.text}}</h2><input type="number" v-model="question.answer" /></div>`,
  props: ['question']
});
```

I've updated your code and implemented the `next` functionality so that you can try and create the `prev` functionality. Of course you should clean this up a little more. Maybe add a property on the question object so it can set what type the `input` should be. Stuff like that to make it more re-useable.

https://jsfiddle.net/9rsuwxvL/2/

Comment: Yes, I'll have to modify the template in the component since I'll need different input for different questions, e.g. input text, radio buttons, select form etc. So I don't think I'll be able to use v-model="question.answer" to obtain the answer. Maybe use querySelectorAll() to get all the answers? I'm not very experienced with JS and Vue.Js so I'm not sure what's the best way to approach the problem.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the answers? Display them or send them to a server?

Comment: I want to display an output depending on the answers using an equation. Right now I'm trying to add input type inside questions so I can manipulate the input method. Can I do this, it doesn't work right now. Here's the fiddle of the attempt, to give you an idea. https://jsfiddle.net/cgrwe0u8/4/

Comment: I added v-bind and it worked. It shows only one radio button, so I'll have to figure out how to add more. https://jsfiddle.net/cgrwe0u8/5/

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how you would display results. With Vue its all about using components to create manageable applications. https://jsfiddle.net/9rsuwxvL/4/

Comment: Thanks, so I'll just have to modify the component to fit my needs. I don't need to output the answer to each question, but provide a result based on weights of each answer and the answer to compute a score that will determine the output. Is there a smart Vue way for eventhandlers, like to make sure user doesn't skip through questions without input? Also next and prev shouldn't appear on the result page.

Comment: All those could be done using components. The Next & Prev could be a navigation component. I've updated my fiddle again to show how the main Vue could have an `isValid` property that the Navigation Component could watch and enable/disable Next depending on the value.  https://jsfiddle.net/9rsuwxvL/6/

Comment: Ok, I checked the fiddle and I see that when I insert a value, I get shown via v-show the message It's valid! I'll need add an alert that when the user clicks next without selecting a value, it notifies them to insert a value. For example with vanilla js, I think you can check that with isNAN() and if it's not to trigger an alert.

Comment: Then in the Question model you should have an `isValid` property that will update when the `answer` value is updated. You saw from the two components example that both components can both view properties on the same model and act accordingly. So in the navigation component you could just pass in that same current question and check if its valid.

Answer (score 1):

If you ever have more than 1 of something, try to use an array, and process it with a loop. In this case you don't need a loop, but it's something to remember.

Since you only need to render one question at a time, just use a computed property to find the current question, based on some index. This index will be increased/decreased by the next/previous buttons.

With the code in this format, if you need to add a question, all you have to do is add it to the array.

https://jsfiddle.net/cgrwe0u8/1/

```
new Vue({
  el: '#quizz',
  data: {
    questions:[
        {question:'How old are you?', answer: ''},
      {question:'How many times do you workout per week?', answer: ''},
    ],
    index:0
  },
  computed:{
    currentQuestion(){
        return this.questions[this.index]
    }
  },
  methods:{
    next(){
        if(this.index + 1 == this.questions.length)
        this.index = 0;
      else
        this.index++;

    },
    previous(){
        if(this.index - 1 < 0)
        this.index = this.questions.length - 1;
      else
        this.index--;
    }
  }

})
```

Comment: Yes, I am going to need a smarter solution, cos I have more than two questions. However, how do I do this if I have different input forms, e.g. radio buttons and text as input for answers. Also, now both next and prev go in circle. I'd like for example to begin with the first question and when I reach the last, not to be able to go any forward. Maybe use some js functions that will hide/show prev and next depending on the questions' index.

Comment: e.g. first question is "What is your gender?" and last 'How many times do you workout per week?'
https://jsfiddle.net/cgrwe0u8/2/

Comment: I have added this two lines in the previous method, to hide prev on the first question, but instead now it behaves differently from intended. It doesn't go back from the first question, which is fine, but when you hit prev, from 2nd or 3rd question it goes back to the 1st.
Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/cgrwe0u8/3/

Comment: I'm sorry but you need to study more javascript. Vue is only going to confuse you more.

Comment: To be honest, I find Vue much simpler than vanilla javascript, you can do most things with less lines of code.